# Unusual structure of a txt file

Tags: r

Having such a text file (example): 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1vq9WjkqkvzTEVEUnlXMGVFa00

Original file has 65k rows.
I need to upload it to R and make processable. I used the following functions:

1. `read.table` - didn't work (R never returned any result)
2. `fread` from `data.table` package - required a lot of manual preprocessing of the file and didn't work as needed as quotes broke the line and the file wasn't in the appropriate form)
3. `scan` got a vector, transformation into matrix didn't bring  needed results.

Desired form of the file is a regular data frame:

```
mydata <- structure(list(fieldName = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("description", 
    "scraped_manufacturer", "title"), class = "factor"), foreign_id = c(13389, 
    13389), is_single_product = structure(1:2, .Label = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), class = "factor"), matched_manufacturers = c("Foden /manId: 76775", 
    "Caterpillar /manId: 74, Skogsjan-Caterpillar /manId: 10329"), 
        matched_products = c("", "C12 /modelId: 32774 /manId: 74"
        ), raw_string = c("CAT FODEN C-12 ENGINE", "CATERPILLAR C-12 ENGINE"
        ), pagesource = structure(c(84L, 84L), .Label = c("", "585e362f6b010083d6962041", 
        "585f270a300000c614b819ed", "585f84be6b0100c6ee962ab1", "585f84dc66010074efac42ca", 
        "585f875a6b0100c7ee963000", "585f878c66010074efac483e", "585f87ad66010075efac4880", 
        "585f88e06b0100b6ee96331c", "585f8b4566010074efac4fcb", "agriaffaires", 
        "apex-auctions", "arlington-plastics-machinery", "auctelia", 
        "auctions-international", "autogilles", "baestlein", "baupool", 
        "bavaria-swiss-ag", "big-iron", "big-machinery", "blackforxx", 
        "blue-group", "bpi-associates", "buk-baumaschinen", "cegema", 
        "christophbusch", "cjm-asset", "classified", "cnc-auction", 
        "cottrill-and-co", "daan", "de-vries", "dechow", "dimex-import-export", 
        "e-farm", "ebay", "ebay-de", "eberle-hald-gmbh", "eggers-landmaschinen", 
        "euro-auctions", "fabricating-machinery-corp", "fastline", 
        "ferwood", "fh-machinery", "first-machinery-auctions-limited", 
        "forklift-international", "ga-tec-gabelstaplertechnik", "gambtec", 
        "geiger", "german-graphics", "goindustry-dovebid", "graf", 
        "gruma-nutzfahrzeuge-gmbh", "hanselmann", "heinrich-kuper-gmbh", 
        "hooray-machinery", "imz-maschinen", "industrial-discount", 
        "ipr-petmachinery", "ironplanet", "ironplanet-com", "karl-guenter-wirths-gmbh", 
        "karner-dechow", "kurt-steiger", "kvd-auctions", "lagermaschinen", 
        "leinweber-landtechnik", "mach4metal", "machinefinder", "machinery-park", 
        "machineryzone", "maschinenbau-rehnen-gmbh", "mideast-equipment", 
        "mmtequipment", "oskar-broziat-maschinen", "perfection-global", 
        "perlick", "perry-videx", "pfeifer-machinery", "plustech-as", 
        "polboto-agri-sp-z-oo", "pressenhaas", "rc-tuxford-exports", 
        "resale", "restlos", "richter-friedewald-gmbh", "ritchie-bros", 
        "rock-and-dirt", "rogiers", "rs-auktionen", "stig-bindner", 
        "surplex", "technikboerse", "themar-trucks", "traktorpool", 
        "unilift", "vebim", "vertimac", "zeppelin-caterpillar", "zoll-auktion", 
        "zuern-gmbh"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("fieldName", 
    "foreign_id", "is_single_product", "matched_manufacturers", "matched_products", 
    "raw_string", "pagesource"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas of how to make it possible to work with the file?

Comment: This is rtf (Rich Text Format). See [Wikipedia page on RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Code_syntax). There is an R package called rtf, but it seems to be only for creating rtf files, not reading them. There is some advice at [This SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634298/parsing-rtf-files-into-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider opening the text file in a software that can read RTF types. On Windows machines, Microsoft Word and the built-in Wordpad can read .rtf documents. And in doing so, a valid json shows in document (without markup content).

[image: JSON text]

Fortunately, R on Windows can connect to the MS Word Object Library using the `RDCOMClient` library where you extract text using the [Document.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821853.aspx) property. Once you read in the json text, use the `jsonlite` library to migrate content to a dataframe:

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(jsonlite)

# OPEN WORD APP
wrdApp = COMCreate("Word.Application")
wrdDoc = wrdApp$Documents()$Open("C:\Path\To\Data.txt")    
wrdtext = wrdDoc[['Content']]

# EXTRACT TEXT TO R VARIABLE
doc = wrdtext$Text()

# CLOSE APP
wrdDoc$Close(FALSE)
wrdApp$Quit()

# RELEASE RESOURCES
wrdtext <- wrdDoc <- wrdApp <- NULL
rm(wrdtext, wrdDoc, wrdApp)
gc()

# RAW DF: NAME / COLUMNS / VALUES LIST TYPES
rawdf <- fromJSON(doc)[[1]][[1]][[1]]

# FINAL DF: NORMALIZING VALUES WITH COL NAMES
finaldf <- setNames(data.frame(rawdf$values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                               rawdf$columns[[1]])
```

**Output**

[image: Final Dataframe]

---

**Alternative**

Should you not have MS Word installed. Launch the CMD prompt and open Wordpad (built-in Windows app) with the command line and copy all content to a .json file (or right click text file and open with Wordpad). Do the counterpart of special app and terminal call if on another OS (Linux/Mac):

```
write "D:\Path\To\Data.txt"
```

After json file is saved, then in R run:

```
rawdf <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paste(reaadLines("C:\Path\To\Data.json", warn=FALSE),
                                      collapse=""), 
                                jsonlite::fromJSON))[[1]][[1]][[1]]

finaldf <- setNames(data.frame(rawdf$values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                    rawdf$columns[[1]])
```

Comment: I use mac so I used the alternative way. Executed the original file in txt format, worked perfectly! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. No doubt, the Mac MS Word also reads `.rtf` formats.